# Is there a way to isolate a running program from the rest of a Linux system?

Tags: chroot, jails, namespace

First of all, I know about virtualisation and containers. I'm sure "he wants containers" is what popped in your mind. (Don't deny it!)

However containers are like chroot: if you want to execute bash in it, you need to copy/mirror a bash executable somewhere in the container FS as well as all the required libs. (If I misunderstood something, please correct me).

---

What I want to know is whether I can start a program like busybox from the current namespace (using the original FS, so no copy needed) and **then** isolate it (for instance using Linux FS namespace) to let it access one unique directory.

Somehow ssh (sftp actually) seems to be able to do something like this without requiring the sshd executable to be in the chrooted FS. But I still lack skills to understand what's going on by myself.

Comment: what about the chroot(2) system call ? (not the chroot(8) command)

Comment: Chroot (as a whole) has been created as  way to change the system root, not as a security feature. That means that I have to check for a dozen of holes and add some constrains to be able to use it correctly. But I agree, a chroot-like function created only for isolation would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for containers.

Or perhaps not. Linux namespaces can be pretty transparent, after all. I don't *believe* there is a way to `unshare` a namespace for a process which has already been called, but you definitely can `unshare` a namespace at call time with little to no effect.

```
cd   /tmp
echo you >hey
sudo unshare -m busybox
echo hey >you; cat  hey
```

---

```
you
```

...and from another terminal...

```
cd   /tmp
cat  you
```

---

```
hey
```

...the mount tree is *shared* by default from the parent namespace, and, though `busybox`'s mount propagation flags are all set to *private* by default, it makes no difference until a change to the mount tree is somehow effected in the namespace. This need not be done *through* busybox, either.

...in `busybox`'s terminal...

```
echo "#$$"
```

---

```
#8854
```

...and now from the other...

```
sudo nsenter -t8854 -m mount -t tmpfs none /tmp
cd .; cat hey
```

---

```
you
```

...but from `busybox`'s terminal, and therefore from the namespace we just effected a `mount`...

```
cd .;  cat hey
```

---

```
cat: hey: no such file or directory
```

...because a new private tmpfs was mounted over the shared `/tmp` in the `nsenter` command...

```
cd ..
umount tmp
cat tmp/hey
```

---

```
you
```